# Change Home Directory location

Tags: directory, home-directory

Just installed a ssd drive with 16.04 how can i point Ubuntu to the old drive for home folder with all my files?

Comment: Domt want to move home just want ubuntu to use old home as default on second drive

Comment: You can mount your old drive as `/home` (eg: `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home`) and to make it persistent add the uuid to `/etc/fstab` as described there

Comment: I think i see what you mean, would you have time to give more detailed instructions? would very much be in your debit !

Answer (score 4):

First use `lsblk` to find the device id of your old drive. It sill be something like `sdb` or `sda`. Now mount it at `/home` for eg:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home
```

Now using `sudo blkid`, note the uuid of your old drive (UUID will be a very long string such as `an0246cg-2kb2-6e8f-ae26-2355691e325b`)

Open `/etc/fstab` in your favorite editor, for eg: `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and add the following at the end.

```
UUID=<noted number from above>    /home    ext4    defaults   0  2
```

Make sure to edit, if necessary, the `ext4` to match the file system in your old drive.

Comment: I have sdb1 for root "/" and sdb2 for "/home" I need to mount "/home" from sdb2 to sdb1 I use your instructions and restart. After it I can't log in to my adccount pasword didn't work. 
Sweet windows in ubuntu every time I must whole system reinstaling over again and agein :(

Comment: But I need only one thing: downsize partition I used GParted but it didn't work, at first I must delete last "SWAP" partition after that I can resizing partition before it, which was mounted as "/home" but I able resize only up not down (I need to make partition smaller not biger)